# How to use my recursive function in Haskell?

Tags: c++, haskell, recursion

```
lol :: IO int
lol = go -1 0 0 0
where go k m n p = case k of
        -1 -> do{
                q <- readLn ;
                go 0 0 0 q
            }
        p -> do{
                putStrLn $ show $ n
            }
        _ -> do{
                q <- readLn ;
                go (k+1) q (if q > m then n+q-m else n) p
                return()
            }
```

I(a haskell beginner) am doing some practise questions. I have written a recursive function but i don't know how to use it in main. Please help me to do solve this problem. This is my idea in C++ and I got it accepted.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long long int prev=0;
    long long int count,ans=0;
    cin >> count;
    long long int p;
    for(int i=0; i<count ;i++){
        cin >> p;
        if(p>prev){
            ans+=p-prev;
        }
        prev=p;
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the function? Explain. In Haskell, recursive functions usually require at least two parameters where there's the head, and the tail of a set of elements.

Answer (score 2):

There are several syntax errors:

- add parentheses around negative numbers when using them as arguments
- to avoid starting a fresh line in the module block, indent `where` (and all following lines) a little bit
- add the missing semicolon to the line before `return ()`

And one type error: you should write `lol :: IO ()`. After fixing these, you may write `main = lol` to use it (or simply name it `main` instead of `lol`). No idea whether it does what it's supposed to do, but that seems like a thing you should be able to test once you get it running.

Answer (score 2):

How about this. I just translated it directly from C++

```hs
module Main where


go :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO Int
go i prev acc
  | i > 0   = do p <- readLn
                 if p > prev
                   then go (i-1) p (acc + (p - prev))
                   else go (i-1) p acc
  | otherwise = return acc

main :: IO ()
main = do
  count <- readLn :: IO Int
  ans <- go count 0 0
  print ans
```

Comment: The way you use `fmap` there will pile up a bunch of "stack". You should make `ans` an argument to `go` (and make it strict). Or use `StateT` or (less efficient) an `IORef`.

Comment: @dfeuer, since you ask :) I did not make `acc` strict, after all, we are striking for clarity hear, not performance.

Comment: With `BangPatterns`, that's as simple as `go i prev !acc = ...`. But I guess you don't feel like a language pragma.

Comment: @dfeuer Precisely. :)